# How to get data resolved in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue-resource, vue-component, vue.js

I'm using `Vue v1.0.28` and `vue-resource` to call my API and get the resource data. So I have a parent component, called **Role**, which has a child **InputOptions**. It has a `foreach` that iterates over the roles.

The big picture of all this is a list of items that can be selected, so the API can return items that are selected beforehand because the user saved/selected them time ago. The point is I can't fill `selectedOptions` of **InputOptions**. How could I get that information from parent component? Is that the way to do it, right?

I pasted here a chunk of my code, to try to show better picture of my problem:

#### role.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="option-blocks">
    <input-options
        :options="roles"
        :selected-options="selected"
        :label-key-name.once="'name'"
        :on-update="onUpdate"
        v-ref:input-options
    ></input-options>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    import InputOptions from 'components/input-options/default'
    import Titles from 'steps/titles'

    export default {
        title: Titles.role,
        components: { InputOptions },
        methods: {
            onUpdate(newSelectedOptions, oldSelectedOptions) {
                this.selected = newSelectedOptions
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                roles: [],
                selected: [],
            }
        },

        ready() {
            this.$http.get('/ajax/roles').then((response) => {
                this.roles = response.body
                this.selected = this.roles.filter(role => role.checked)
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### InputOptions

```
<template>
    <ul class="option-blocks centered">
        <li class="option-block" :class="{ active: isSelected(option) }" v-for="option in options" @click="toggleSelect(option)">
            <label>{{ option[labelKeyName] }}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    import Props from 'components/input-options/mixins/props'

    export default {
        mixins: [ Props ],
        computed: {
            isSingleSelection() {
              return 1 === this.max
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleSelect(option) {
                //...
            },
            isSelected(option) {
                return this.selectedOptions.includes(option)
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {}
        },

        ready() {
            // I can't figure out how to do it
            // I guess it's here where I need to get that information,
            // resolved in a promise of the parent component
            this.$watch('selectedOptions', this.onUpdate)
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Props

```
export default {
    props: {
        options: {
            required: true
        },
        labelKeyName: {
            required: true
        },
        max: {},
        min: {},
        onUpdate: {
            required: true
        },
        noneOptionLabel: {},
        selectedOptions: {
            type: Array
            default: () => []
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I'm now getting this warning in the console:

`[Vue warn]: Data field "selectedOptions" is already defined as a prop. To provide default value for a prop, use the "default" prop option; if you want to pass prop values to an instantiation call, use the "propsData" option. (found in component: <default-input-options>)`

Comment: I hope you are not using Vue because of GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Vue.js version 2.0.3? If so, there is no `ready` function as specified in http://vuejs.org/api. You can do it in `created` hook of the component as follows:

```js
// InputOptions component
// ...
data: function() {
    return {
        selectedOptions: []
    }
},
created: function() {
    this.$watch('selectedOptions', this.onUpdate)
}
```

In your `InputOptions` component, you have the following code:

```js
this.$watch('selectedOptions', this.onUpdate)
```

But I am unable to see a `onUpdate` function defined in `methods`. Instead, it is defined in the parent component `role`. Can you insert a `console.log("selectedOptions updated")` to check if it is getting called as per your expectation? I think Vue.js expects methods to be present in the same component.

Alternatively in the above case, I think you are allowed to do `this.$parent.onUpdate` inside `this.$watch(...)` - something I have not tried but might work for you.

**EDIT: some more thoughts**

You may have few more issues - you are trying to observe an array - `selectedOptions` which is a risky strategy. Arrays don't change - they are like containers for list of objects. But the individual objects inside will change. Therefore your `$watch` might not trigger for `selectedOptions`.

Based on my experience with Vue.js till now, I have observed that array changes are registered when you add or delete an item, but not when you change a single object - something you need to verify on your own.

To work around this behaviour, you may have separate component (`input-one-option`) for each of your input options, in which it is easier to observe changes.

Comment: Even `onUpdate` function being in parent controller, it's working properly. Actually `selected` (Role) and `selectedOptions` (InputOptions) arrays are being updated as expected.

The real problem is I can't initialise `selectedOptions` with the items returned from the API. The big picture of all this is a list of items that can be selected, so the API can return items that are selected beforehand because the user saved/selected them time ago. So, what I cannot do its to pass those selected items from Role (parent) to InputOptions (child)

Comment: Added v1.0.28 as version used

Comment: Then `ready` function works. Based on your earlier comment, if you have trouble initializing `selectedOptions`, then you need to verify the api data with `console.log(response.body)` inside the `ready` function of parent component. If you get an array of role objects containing a `checked` field with boolean values (not string), then `selectedOptions` should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the bug. I wasn't binding the prop as kebab-case